# Json to Datatables seems invalid format

Tags: javascript, json, api, datatables

I'm quite new here and I am working with javascript and data manipulation using Datatables.

My api returs json data like this:

> 

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "qwert",
        "lastname": "qwert",
        "school": "qwert",
        "parents": "qwert",
        "About": "qqwewqeqwewqe"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "qwert",
        "lastname": "qweere",
        "school": "sadsadasd",
        "parents": "asdasdasd",
        "About": "asdasdasdasdasdasdas"
    }
]
```

> 

I have tried the following JS code with Datatables but doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#tableofrequirement').DataTable({
      ajax: 'example2.json',
        "columns":[
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'lastname'},
            {data: 'school'},
            {data: 'parents'},
            {data: 'About'},
        ]
        
   });
});
```

I have noticed, however, that if I download the json data and I manually change the format to the below the function works perfectly:

```
{
"data ":[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "qwert",
            "lastname": "qwert",
            "school": "qwert",
            "parents": "qwert",
            "About": "qqwewqeqwewqe"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "qwert",
            "lastname": "qweere",
            "school": "sadsadasd",
            "parents": "asdasdasd",
            "About": "asdasdasdasdasdasdas"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way I can tell Datatables the structure of my json or is there anyway I can easily reformat this on javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [this page](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/) in the documentation for the different formats that DataTables can accept from Ajax. I think you want the "flat array" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned json from you api is not valid, you are missing quotatin marks around this value `"lastname": qwert,` I added an example with correct json data and it works just fine.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "qwert",
        "lastname": "qwert",
        "school": "qwert",
        "parents": "qwert",
        "About": "qqwewqeqwewqe"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "qwert",
        "lastname": "qweere",
        "school": "sadsadasd",
        "parents": "asdasdasd",
        "About": "asdasdasdasdasdasdas"
    }
];

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#table_id').DataTable({
   data: data,
        columns:[
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'lastname'},
            {data: 'school'},
            {data: 'parents'},
            {data: 'About'},
        ]
        
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="table_id" class="display">

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It does work, your a genius!